# java - buffered readed readline() gives null as end of file but no way to use that null

Tags: java, stream, eof

Is there a way to check whether a file was correctly written, I mean if there is an EOF at the end?
I'm asking that because I have a program that takes some file, merge them in a very big file and then use it to get statistics from it.
The point is that the second part never ends because it doesn't recognize the end of file.

The relevant parts of the code are the following:
(please do not ask for the whole code as I cannot post for important reasons)

```
    FileWriter file=null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    String pathToRead=null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null ;
    FileInputStream fis = null ;
    TestJFileChooser d=new TestJFileChooser();
    int c=1;
            String line=null;

    ....

    //here i select the files

    selectedFile=new File(pathToRead);

    //here I get one buffer reader for each file got with listFiles()

    for(File file_sel:app){
        if (file_sel.getName().startsWith("gtou")){
            System.out.println(file_sel.getName());
            fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file_sel);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            isr=new InputStreamReader(fis);
            br=new BufferedReader(isr);
            map.put(i, br);
            num_file++;
            i++; 
        }
    }

    //then I select the output file and open a print writer for it

    fileToWrite=new File(pathToRead);
        try {
            file = new FileWriter(fileToWrite);
            pw= new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //merging part
        ....
        line=br.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
        System.out.println("line is:"+line);
        ....
        line=br.readLine();
        }   


       //end of merging ....

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

        try {
            if (file!=null) file.close();
            fis.close();
            isr.close();
            br.close();
            for(int fi=0;fi<num_file;fi++){
                br2=map.get(fi);
                br2.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        so.kill();
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        r.gc();

    //this is a popup that comes out 
    GlitchSquad gli=new GlitchSquad("Completed");
```

the problem is that as output I get:

```
line is: null ; 
line is: null ; 
line is: null ;
```

etc
And never get to "completed" popup =(

I cannot understand what is exactly that null because the control line!=null doesn't work.
I also tried to use that null as a string ..but nothing..
I thought that was a problem in how I close the streams but now the code seems correct to me ..but still no way to stop it..

Suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

p.s. it is a summarized version in order to focus on the streams.. variables are correctly declared and the same is for imports etc

edit: code updated

Comment: It is not possible for that code to produce that output. Either you aren't running that code, or, incredibly, your file contains lines containing the string "null".

Comment: EJB is right, you should just write a example-program that is actually run and post the output and code of this prog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem, but I'd be using this code instead:

```
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file_sel);
    isr=new InputStreamReader(fis);
    br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    map.put(num_file++, br);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Otherwise there may be uncaught "NullPointer"-exceptions or strange BufferedReaders in your "map". ( I don't right now know how `new InputStreamReader(null)` will behave.)

It looks like i and num_file have always equal values, so just drop i. Or use a LinkedList and drop both.

If there's not a special merging that you have to do, I'd just do it like this:

```
OutputStream os;
try {
    os = new FileOuputStream(outfile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    os = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (os != null) {
    for(File file_sel:app) {
        if (file_sel.getName().startsWith("gtou")) {
            System.out.println(file_sel.getName());
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(file_sel);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int readBytes = 0;
                while ((readBytes = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                fos.flush();
                is.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you read files with different encodings, you will have to modify at least the reading of course.

If it doesn't work, I'd suggest you build a "summarized" and runable sample program.

Answer (score 0):

EOF is EOF. There is no more data. Unless you have an expected EOF mark within the file, or a self-describing protocol that tells you where the EOF mark should be, there is no way to determine whether the file was completely written.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is this code:

```
    BufferedReader br = ...
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println("line is:" + line);
        ...
        line = br.readLine();
    }
```

You say that this repeatedly outputs this:

```
line is: null ;
line is: null ;
```

(Notice the " ;" on the end!!!)

The *only way that can happen* is if the file you are reading contains at least one line that look like this:

```
null ;
```

Indeed, unless the "..." code includes a `continue` statement, there must must be lots of those lines in the input file.

---

> Is there a way to check whether a file was correctly written?

Yea.  Look at it using a text editor and/or check its file size.

> I mean if there is an EOF at the end?

In modern file systems, EOF is a position not a marker.  Specifically it is the position after the last byte of the file.  So it is logically impossible for a file to not have an EOF.  (You'd have to have a file that is *infinite* in length for there to be no EOF.)